# How to import this dita 1.3 xml?

Tags: dita, dita-ot

Could somebody help poor developer with upgrading to Dita 1.3 :)

I need to make dita-ot work with newer version of xml's I was given (example below). I need to adjust something in the library but I don't have any clue where to start. I've replaced the problematic bit just for example - //FOOBAR/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//FOOBAR//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "file:///D:/InfoShare/Web/Author/ASP/DocTypes/dita-sdl/1.3/dtd/technicalContent/dtd/sdlConcept.dtd">
<?ish ishref="GUID-874B737D-F63A-48C3-887A-571C38D5ED5A" version="1" lang="en-us"?>
<concept xml:lang="en-us" id="xs_help_me_contextually_please" rev="for Desktop" product="Foobar product">
   <title id="GUID-F92ED443-BE97-44C7-AB36-726B2A76ECF9">New DITA declaration topic without any new elements</title>
   <shortdesc id="GUID-8D7A677D-6782-4A65-96B4-F7F4B3CB5CCD">
      <ph>Short description of the topic.</ph>
   </shortdesc>
   <prolog>
      <metadata>
         <category>
            Content area
            <keyword>Templates</keyword>
         </category>
         <keywords>
            <indexterm id="GUID-32379B47-E4F9-4E00-A8A7-383584241D88">indexterm</indexterm>
         </keywords>
      </metadata>
   </prolog>
   <conbody>
      <p id="GUID-A2466389-DC06-4052-A0EE-8684F3C3D7D3">
         <ph>Text here.</ph>
      </p>
   </conbody>
</concept>
```

If I change FOOBAR TO OASIS, then it seems to work - at least it does not give any error. The
command that I'm running is:

```
dita -i=/app/dita/in/foobar.ditamap -f=xhtml -o=/app/dita/out
```

The error it gives:

```
[gen-list] [DOTJ079E][ERROR] File 'file:/app/dita/in/xs_help_me_contextually_please.xml' could not be loaded. Ensure that grammar files for this document type are referenced and installed properly. Cannot load file: /D:/InfoShare/Web/Author/ASP/DocTypes/dita-sdl/1.3/dtd/technicalContent/dtd/sdlConcept.dtd (No such file or directory)
[move-meta] I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/tmp/temp20191106165059386/in/xs_help_me_contextually_please.xml: /tmp/temp20191106165059386/in/xs_help_me_contextually_please.xml (No such file or directory)
[move-meta] file:/app/dita/in/foobar.ditamap:3:327: [DOTX026W][WARN]: Unable to retrieve linktext from target: 'xs_help_me_contextually_please.xml'. Using navigation title as fallback.
```

Also I should add the technicalContent/dtd/sdlConcept.dtd (that I was also given) somewhere in the library but not sure where. Tried to put it in plugins/org.oasis-open.dita.v1_3 and thought it works but when removing the file and having //OAOSIS/ in the source xml, then it didn't give out any error either.

How can it all work if the path is file:///D:/InfoShare/Web/Author/ASP/Doc... that does not exist in the system where the import happens (Docker container). Is it just informational?

Very confused of all of this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to help you given what you have provided, but I can add some clarifying information:

1. You are working with DITA source that either is (or has been stored) in the SDL CCMS. Depending on the age of the SDL product it has different names: Trisoft, SDL Live Content, SDL Tridion Docs.
2. DITA 1.3 is backwards compatible with all previous versions of DITA, so you should not have to adjust any DITA source files. But -- if the DITA source uses different DTDs -- as any content stored in the SDL product does, you'll need those DTDs, as they are different than the OASIS DTDs that ship with DITA-OT.

Hope this helps a little; you also might have better luck posting on the dita-users list at Yahoo!

Best,
Kris

Comment: Thank you! That's already more information I had!
Am I looking at creating new plugin for Dita-OT that supports //FOOBAR namespace? I was given dita-sdl.zip package but there's no word about FOOBAR in it so I can't see what's the connection (sorry for using foobar but don't want to use the original here :) ). It looks like it's plugin itself: there's 1.3 folder and in that there are schema-url, schema, rng, dtd folders and catalog.xml file.

Comment: They re-thought the plan and changed the xml's to be more future proof by making it compatible with dita-ot library out of the box.